# Getting empty response while doing async and await

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js and javascript. I get confused in my code as It give me empty response. I am trying to implement the promise and async and await feature however getting respones {}.

Could anybody help me to understand where I am wrong.

Please see below code may be it will long however I need help on issue of await where I am not getting empty result

```
var response = {};
var newSecret ='';
class FabricClientRegister {
    constructor() {
        console.log("called constructer");
    }

    async RegisterUser(Username, roleid) {
        try {
            const setAsyncTimeout = (cb, timeout = 0) => new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    cb();
                    resolve();
                }, timeout);
            });


            let query1 = {}
            query1.RoleID = roleid;
            //   query1.name = ''; 
            var name ='';
            console.log('roleid',roleid)
            //   console.log('Username',Username);
            var fs = require('fs');
            var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config/Config.json', 'utf8'));

            // var Username = req.body.username;
            console.log('Username',Username)

            const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
            const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
            console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

            // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
            const userExists = await wallet.exists(Username);
            if (userExists) {
                response.data = null;
                response.httpstatus = 400;
                response.message = `An identity for the  ${Username} already exists in the wallet`;
                return response;
            }
            console.log("Username1",Username)
            // Check to see if we've already enrolled the admin user.
            const adminExists = await wallet.exists(appAdmin);
            if (!adminExists) {
                response.data = null;
                response.httpstatus = 400;
                response.message = "Am admin identity is not registered . please register admin first";
                return response;
            }

            // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
            const gateway = new Gateway();
            await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: appAdmin,  discovery: { enabled: false, asLocalhost: true }
                /*** Uncomment lines below to disable commit listener on submit ****/
                , eventHandlerOptions: {
                    strategy: null
                }
            });

            // Get the CA client object from the gateway for interacting with the CA.
            const ca = gateway.getClient().getCertificateAuthority();
            const adminIdentity = gateway.getCurrentIdentity();
            console.log("Username4",Username)

            MongoClient.connect(config.Database.DFARM.connectString, async function (err, client) {
                if (err) {
                    let connError = new Error(500, "Error connecting to DFARM database", err);
                    res.status(connError.status).json(connError);
                }
                else {
                    client.db(config.Database.DFARM.dbName).collection("Role").find(query1).toArray(function (err, docs) {
                        if(err) {
                            console.log('err db',err);
                        } else{
                            console.log('Role name DB',docs);
                            name = docs[0].name;
                            query1.name = name;
                            console.log('Role',query1);
                        }
                        client.close();
                    })
                }
            })

            setTimeout(() => console.log('Role 10',query1.name), 5 * 1000);

            const doStuffAsync = async () => {

            setAsyncTimeout( async () => {
                console.log('Role Name',query1.name);
                const secret =  await ca.register({enrollmentID: Username, role: query1.name}, adminIdentity);
                console.log('secret',secret);
                response.secret = secret;
                newSecret = secret;
                console.log('newSecret', newSecret );

                response.httpstatus = 200;
                response.message = `Successfully registered admin user ${Username} and imported it into the wallet`;
                return response;
                }, 10000);
            };

            doStuffAsync();
        //      .then(function(result) {
        //     //     console.log('promise result',result) // error here undefined
        //      }).catch(err)
        //      {
        //          console.log("eee", err)
        //      };
            console.log('newSecret1', newSecret)
            console.log('respones', response)
            return newSecret;
        } catch (error) {
            response.error = error;
            response.httpstatus = 500;
            response.message = "Failed to enroll admin due to above error";
            return response;
        }
    }
};
```

Please see below output in CLI

```
Username Abhinav345
called constructer
roleid 1
Username Abhinav345
Wallet path: /vagrant/Dfarm-app/dFarmUserService/dFarmUserService/wallet
Username1 Abhinav345
Username4 Abhinav345
newSecret1 
respones {} //getting empty one however need some data
data result 
Role name DB [ { _id: 5d029dec7e8409b489e04cff,
    appName: 'Farmer',
    RoleID: 1,
    name: 'farmer',
    routes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    tabs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]
Role { RoleID: 1, name: 'farmer' }
Role 10 farmer
Role Name farmer
secret XXCephExVetS
newSecret XXCephExVetS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider put `await` before `doStuffAsync()`.

Comment: Thanks @Douglas however its give same result as empty

Comment: @Abhijeet1234, what if `await` before `setAsyncTimeout`? I believe your code is not running asynchronously.

Comment: May be you right I have check the all the Async function and change it according to asynchronously

Comment: I have take some code info from https://www.davebitter.com/articles/async-set-timeout.html

Comment: I have make changes as per in link above its give me something like as result 
 "secret Promise { <pending> }
newSecret Promise { <pending> }
newSecret1 Promise { <pending> }
respones { secret: Promise { <pending> },"